# Celery, route all tasks in a Django project to a specific queue

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a machine which runs two copies of the same Django project, let's call them *A* and *B*, and I want to use Celery to process background tasks.

I set up supervisor to launch two workers, one for each project, but given the tasks have the same names in both projects, sometimes tasks are run by the wrong worker.

My next step was to use a different *queue* for each worker, using the `-Q queueName` parameter. Using `rabbitmqctl list_queues` I could see that both queues were created. The command I'm using to issue the workers is

```
python3 -m celery worker -A project -l INFO -Q q1 --hostname=celery1@ubuntu
```

and

```
python3 -m celery worker -A project -l INFO -Q q2 --hostname=celery2@ubuntu
```

The question is, how do I route all the tasks from *project A* to *queue A*, and all tasks from *project B* to *queue B*? Yes, I've seen you can add a parameter to the `task` decorator to select the queue, but I'm looking for a global setting or something like that.

**Edit 1**: I've tried using `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` but it doesn't work, the setting gets ignored. I've also tried creating a dumb Router, like this:

```
class MyRouter(object):
    def route_for_task(self, task, args=None, kwargs=None):
        return 'q1'

CELERY_ROUTES = (MyRouter(), )
```

And it works (obviously return different queues in each project), but I'm baffled, why is the `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` setting ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end it was easier than I expected. I just had to set up both the default queue and the default routing key (and optionally the default exchange, as long as it's a `direct` exchange).

```
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'q2'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'q2'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'q2'
```

I had some concepts unclear, but after following the [official RabbitMQ's tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) they got much clearer and I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: Gosh, you can't imagine how close I was to smash my head after struggling on the exact same issue. It's even more confusing now because celery 4.4 has a different set of variables (CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE, CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE, CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY), with some outdated documentation, making it hard to understand what should be done for your celery version. Anyway, your solution worked, thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU. Same issue for a few hours with a erroneous "received unregistered task of type..." in the log. On a timeline, ended up building a separate vm as ids across the two django apps pointed to different objs causing all sorts of grief but only sometimes. Shortly after landed here.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the task routing as

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'services.qosservice.*': {'queue': 'qos_celery'},
}
```

The `*` is the celery-supported wildcard.

Reference: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#automatic-routing

Answer (score 0):

I think you must define rouing in settings.py

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {

    'services.qosservice.set_qos_for_vm': {'queue': 'qos_celery'},

    'services.qosservice.qos_recovery': {'queue': 'qos_celery'},

    'services.qosservice.qos_recovery_compute': {'queue': 'qos_celery_1'},

}
```

In my exmaple. task set_qos_for_vm will be routing to qos_celery queue and task qos_recovery_compute queue will be routing to qos_celery_1.

More detail: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#id2

Hope it help you

Comment: Do I have to list all the tasks? Isn't there anything like a wildcard?